# Windows Azure WADLogs Query is very slow

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I've noticed that querying a WADs table e.g. WADLogs is very very slow. It takes up to 5minute to return 10 records.

Yes the WADs table are very large in our scenario. Still, I wasn't expecting this slow. It takes ages to troubleshoot the production issues.

Question I've:

1. Could anyone please share best way to manage the WADs table so that query is faster.
2. Is there anyway to optimize the WADs tabels
3. Is there a best practice what should and should not be done when logging on to WADs
4. Are there any best practices on purging/backing up etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaurav Mantri has a [post](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/) explaining how to query WAD tables in a performant manner. The bottom line is that you need to query on PartitionKey and RowKey to avoid a performance-killing table scan. The PartitionKey for the WAD tables contains the TickCount in a slightly encoded form and an appropriately constructed value can be used for range queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Neil for the link.

Summary:

1. Use PartionKey attribute which is indexed by Table Storage.

Where,

PartionKey = "0"+ DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1.0).Ticks

Usage for REST API Query ($filter) criteria: 
*PartitionKey ge ’0634012319404982640′*